# Carthagenet node not bootstrapped after snapshot import

Tags: node, snapshots

I am trying to get a fully synchronized Carthagenet node.
I did the following steps :

- wget carthagenet.sh
- execute ./carthagenet.sh start
- execute ./carthagenet.sh shell

  - wget snapshot.full (24h old snapshot from https://snapshots.tulip.tools/#/)
  - tezos-node snapshot import snapshot.full
  - exit

After that I executed `sudo ./carthagenet.sh client bootstrapped` and I was expecting to see the blocks of current day getting downloaded.

But in fact the node was still synchronizing blocks with timestamps from 2-3 months ago and then it stops at a block with timestamp "2019-12-12T20:29:27-00:00"

What is the right procedure to get a fully synchronized carthagenet node?

Thank you for your help